# how do I display xml feeds in tabular format in elixir

Tags: json, xml, rss, elixir

I am trying to read XML feeds form "http://www.rssboard.org/files/sample-rss-2.xml"

I am able to get one column(title) in Enum (Enum.each(XmlNode.all) but how do I get another column like description to show up in table format shown below?

Fetcher.ex:

```
{:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: body}} = HTTPoison.get("http://www.rssboard.org/files/sample-rss-2.xml")
 doc = XmlNode.from_string(body) 

# This prints only title and not description along with it. 
# I want to get title and description in tabular format
 Enum.each(XmlNode.all(doc, "//title"), fn(node) ->
 IO.puts "#{XmlNode.node_name(node)} #{XmlNode.attr(node,"Title:")} end)
```

XMLNode.ex:

```
defmodule XmlNode do
  require Record
  Record.defrecord :xmlAttribute, Record.extract(:xmlAttribute, from_lib: "xmerl/include/xmerl.hrl")
  Record.defrecord :xmlText, Record.extract(:xmlText, from_lib: "xmerl/include/xmerl.hrl")

  def from_string(xml_string, options \\ [quiet: true]) do
    {doc, []} =
      xml_string
      |> :binary.bin_to_list
      |> :xmerl_scan.string(options)

    doc
  end

  def all(node, path) do
    for child_element <- xpath(node, path) do
      child_element
    end
  end

  def first(node, path), do: node |> xpath(path) |> take_one
  defp take_one([head | _]), do: head
  defp take_one(_), do: nil

  def node_name(nil), do: nil
  def node_name(node), do: elem(node, 1)

  def attr(node, name), do: node |> xpath('./@#{name}') |> extract_attr
  defp extract_attr([xmlAttribute(value: value)]), do: List.to_string(value)
  defp extract_attr(_), do: nil

  def text(node), do: node |> xpath('./text()') |> extract_text
  defp extract_text([xmlText(value: value)]), do: List.to_string(value)
  defp extract_text(_x), do: nil

  defp xpath(nil, _), do: []
  defp xpath(node, path) do
    :xmerl_xpath.string(to_char_list(path), node)
  end
end
```

Expected output:

```
Title    |    Description
-------------------------------
title 1   |  description 1
title 2   | description 2
```

Comment: Where are you having problems? Is it in extracting the field values for the table, or for printing in a tabular format? For the latter, take a look at the `String.pad_leading` & `String.pad_trailing` functions.

Comment: I have problems in both in extracting the field values for the table as well as  for printing in a tabular format.
As of now I am able to print only single column, how do I get another column ? And how do I print in tabular format.